# Keras Python - Is there a way to NOT get averaged metrics?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

After reading the Keras documentation and spending several hours searching, I couldn't find a way, except using **[BaseLogger class that seems to be broken](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15246)**, to access the "raw" loss and accuracy metrics after each batch and epoch. Is this possible?

Comment: If not averaged metrics, exactly what do you want to compute?

Comment: For each batch, i would like to access to the real computed loss, that using for example binary crossentropy, would be 1/(batch_size) * (sum(loss_function)). Of course it makes sense to have the final averaged result for each epoch, but i can't understand why i can't access, for the i-th batch of each epoch, to the computed loss. We have instead the "average up to the i-th batch"

Comment: That does not really answer what I asked, in any case, Metrics can always access predictions for each batch, the averaging is implemented in each metrics/loss.

Comment: I explain me better doing an example: at the beginning of the first epoch, the first batch will have a specific loss that is 0.4 , and now we don't care how it is computed. At the second batch, we'll have the second loss, that is for example 0.8. What i see will be 0.8+0.4/2 = 0.6. If we have 3 steps_per_epochand the last batch loss is 0.3, the final averaged epoch loss is (0.3+0.4+0.8)/3, and i can't see the values 0.8, 0.3, from which i got from Keras doc. I would just understand if it's possible to access to that values, or if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes there are ways to see those values.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a way? I would be grateful.

Comment: Sure, for this you need to create a custom Callback and implement the on_train_batch_end method, and use your callback during fitting.

Comment: I've already tried this way. I can just access to a "log" variable that contains the averaged loss up to that batch. So if the batch is the last of an epoch, its loss is the same of the final average loss computed for the epoch. Since it's important to have the final loss of each epoch, it doesn't matter, my question was more for curiosity since i couldn't find an easy way to get the single (not averaged) computed value of each batch. Thanks.